# querySelector("selector") vs querySelector("selector").value

Tags: javascript, string, input

So I made a small beginner app which reverse words. Additional target was to clear the input after user presses the button.
When I assign input as selector without value and then I add the value

```
word.value = "";
```

works just fine. But if I assign input.value then suddenly

```
word = "";
```

doesn't work. Here I completely don't understand it, as it seems to load the value onclick so it should be able to change it (in my mind). Could anyone explain why the second way doesn't work?

Working just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/2kc80sw6/
Not working as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/0fnbvqtw/

Comment: `word.value = ""` set the value property `word = ""` set the `word` variable.

Comment: Oh, that was pretty simple solution... `word == ""` also works as expected, thank you.